# Is there any example of a property which is true but undecidable?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, integers, decidability

Yesterday I thought I had found a paradox about undecidable statements. Let's say there is some property P about integers, which is formulated as follows: ∀ n ∈ ℕ, something(n). Where "something" is a algebraic expression about n. Let's also assume that P has been proven to be undecidable.

Now, here is my train of thoughts: let's assume that there exists an integer k ∈ ℕ such that something(k) is false. In this case, it's easy to prove P to be false by just providing this counter-example. So that would mean that P is decidable since it's provably false. That is inconsistent with the assumption that P is undecidable, so it must mean that there isn't any k ∈ ℕ such that something(k) is false, but then we just proved that P is true, which is also inconsistent with the fact that it is undecidable.

Trying to understand this paradox, I found this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem#Examples_of_undecidable_statements):

> Undecidability of a statement in a particular deductive system does not, in and of itself, address the question of whether the truth value of the statement is well-defined, or whether it can be determined by other means. Undecidability only implies that the particular deductive system being considered does not prove the truth or falsity of the statement. Whether there exist so-called "absolutely undecidable" statements, whose truth value can never be known or is ill-specified, is a controversial point among various philosophical schools.

Which, in this context, I interpret by the idea that finding a counter-example k ∈ ℕ such that something(k) is false is **not inconsistant with** the undecidability of P, because the process of finding a counter-example is unrelated to the process of proving the statement true or false by deduction, and the undecidability of P only relates to deduction.

So, assuming this interpretation is correct, my question is : is there any example of such property P which we know is true or false thanks to examples/counter-examples, but which, regardless, has been proven undecidable?

Comment: A sentence of form $\forall x Px$ (with $P$ an arithmetical property) if false it is *disprovable*: as you say, it is enough to check all numbers until we find the $k$ such that $P(k)$ does not hold, and this is a proof of the falsity of $\forall x Px$. Thus, if $\forall x Px$ is *undecidable* (we have a proof of this fact in the metatheory of the theory to which $\forall x Px$ belongs) it must be true (contraposing the argument above: if false, then we can decide it).

Comment: If we can prove it's undecidable, then we have proved it's true and thus not undecidable. So, we can't prove such a statement is undecidable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you expand on why the proof of falsity from the counter-example belongs to the scope of "decidability", but not the resulting proof of truthiness?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My paradox is definitely applicable to some known [undecidable statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC), although not necessarily in this exact form. For example, it has been proved that there exist some polynomial p ∈ Z[x1, ..., x9] such that the existence of integers m1, ..., m9  such that p(m1, ..., m9) = 0 is undecidable. My paradox works for this undecidable problem by starting with "let's assume that there exists integers m1, ..., m9 such that p(m1, ..., m9) = 0" and so on.

Comment: The statement that there are diophantine equations for which the existence of solutions is undecidable isn't a statement of the form "for all n P(n)," is it? I thought the conversation was about things like Goldbach's conjecture, where if it's false then it's false because there exists a counterexample, and if there's a counterexample then you can find it, so if it's false then it's decidable, so if it's undecidable then it's true, so a proof of undecidability is a proof of truth, and that's why it can't be undecidable. The diophantine equation result is of an entirely different nature.

Comment: I don't understand why it's different. By paraphrasing your formulation of the paradox: if there is a solution to the diophantine equation then you can find it, so if it's true then it's decidable, so if it's undecidable then it's false, so a proof of undecidability is a proof of falsity, and that's why it can't be undecidable?

Comment: Joerg Resag clarifies this nice in his article you can find if you search "Die Grenzen der Berechenbarkeit" , but the site is in german. The main point is that if a statement like Goldbach or the unsolvability of some diophantine equation is undecidable in some theory (for example PA) , then this fact cannot be proven WITHIN this theory, but a stronger theory (for example ZFC) might be able to prove this.Goedel's completeness theorem states that the provable statements are exactly those statements that are true with respect to every interpretation.